# sqllite database with Flask not instantiating

Tags: python, html, flask, typeerror, backend

I'm trying to make a todo list web app with Flask. I need to make an instance of a database to store the tasks. For some reason when I try to make the instance it doesn't work. I am sure this is the issue because when I remove the part that uses the database from the code it runs fine.

Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

flask1 = Flask(__name__)
# I think this is telling our app where to look for the database
# Three slashes == relative path. four == absolute path
flask1.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db'

# initializing the database
db = SQLAlchemy(flask1)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.ctime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Task %r>" % self.id

    # To actually instatiate the database
    # 1- start python shell
    # 2- import db
    # 3- db.create_all()
    # 4- exit shell


@flask1.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_content = request.form['content']
        new_task = Todo(content=task_content)

        try:
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/')
        except:
            return 'there was an issue adding the task'
    else:
        tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).first
        return render_template('index.html', tasks=tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask1.run(debug=True)
```

Now in the else block, if I return render_template like *this*

```
return render_template('index.html')
```

There is no error. This is because I use the *tasks* variable in my index.html file

Here is the code HTML code that generates the error

```
<!-- {% for task in tasks %} -->
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task.content }}</td>
                <td> {{task.date_created.date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="">delete</a>
                    <br>
                    <a href="">Update</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <!-- {% endfor %} -->
```

The error I'm getting right now is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. I believe this means that the instance of my database was not successfully created.

I try to create the db instance in the following method
1- open python shell
2- import this script
3- db.create_all()
4- exit python shell

Any help is appreciated
Sorry for a long question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to get all the tasks and call `all()`:

```
tasks = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.date_created).all()
```

Comment: Yes that was it. Thank you